# Arduino Uno not appearing under ports

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, uploading

I have an Arduino Uno attached to my MacBook Air running the Arduino IDE 1.6.4.

The Arduino was visible in the Serial port section this morning, but then it just disappeared. The ON light on the Arduino still comes on, but I cannot connect to it through the port section. I attached the Uno to another computer and it did not appear there either. However, when a different Arduino is connected to my computer it does show up. I also tried using a different IDE version, and it did not appear there either.

All of the other topics I found regarding this were saying it is the OS's fault, but since I was able to see the other Arduino, I am pretty sure it is not. I updated the FTDI drivers, and I tried using a powered hub and it is still not there.

UPDATE:

When I took the chip out of the UNO that is not appearing and put it into a working UNO, I was able to see it, is it possible that the Serial port is just not working, and if so how would I fix that

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider that your arduino is may be burned.

Comment: Is anything plugged in to the arduino? does its power light come on? Can you tell if its running the last program you uploaded still?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case since it works on another computer...

Comment: Step one: from a terminal, run `sudo dmesg` and note the last line.  Step two, plug in the Arduino.  Step three: run `sudo dmesg` again and find the same last line.  Step four: post what comes after that line into your question.

Comment: @BrettAM There were things pluged into the arduino but I took them off and the arduino still did not show up, the power light is on, and I am not sure is the last program running because all it did was print to the serial monitor.

Comment: @Akkilah I do not think so, as the power light still comes on

Comment: @Majenko On both times the last line remained the same, it is 'Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80145feb40) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80145feb40, region 0x7fff97c00000->0x7fff97e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.'

Comment: Are you plugging it directly into the mac or into a hub? If it's a hub, is it a powered hub?

Comment: @Majenko I am plugging it directly into my mac

Comment: I have an UNO where I have to hold the cable at the right angle for it to register.  The fault is with the USB socket on the UNO.  Try applying pressure to the plug from different angles.

Comment: @Majenko No that did not work, I do not think it is the cables fault, as the same cable works fine with another uno

Comment: As I said, the fault with mine is the socket, not the cable - the contacts inside the socket don't make good contact with the plug.

Comment: @Majenko The same socket also works fine with another arduino using the same cable

Comment: That makes no sense - I am talking about the socket *on the Arduino itself* - how can you swap that to another Arduino?!

Comment: @Majenko Sorry I was quick reading, I tried holding the cable at different angles to the uno's socket but it is still not appering up on the computer

Comment: @Akkilah Is there a way to check

Comment: @user10529: if you got anther PC go and try on it

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: at first i though i didn't read his post correctly , but after reading it again , there was no mention of him trying the problematic UNO in a different PC

Comment: @Akkilah I tried it on another computer on another computer and it still did not show up

Comment: @user10529 : if it for my i would count it as fired, but you can  check this link if you really wanna make sure its burned  http://goo.gl/gtHtgR

Comment: @Akkilah The green led on mine does come on. The led on pin 13 does not come on because I have changed the sketch

Comment: @Akkilah Is there anything I can do if it is fried

Comment: @user10529 : Im wondering if your older sketch ( the last  one u uploaded to the bored) still working ?

Comment: @Akkilah Unfortunately all that sketch did was print something to the Serial Monitor(it was a I2Cscanner)

Comment: @user10529: you can check the answer given in this link http://goo.gl/BDJJwZ as im actually run out of idea

Comment: @Akkilah Is there a way to check what part of it is fired

Comment: @user10529 : have you tried to re-upload bootloader to ur UNO

Comment: @Akkilah No i looked into it but you need to get special equipment

Comment: @user10529 : just use on of ur working arduino as AVRISP Programmer, u can check this link http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

If the Arduino doesn't show up on multiple computers, and others do, it may be bricked, or dead. You might try reflashing the chip, and hope that solves your issue. If it doesn't, chances are it's toast.

If however the device simply doesn't show up on one computer, but does on another. It's either a software issue, or a USB issue with that computer.

If winblows OS, try reinstalling, or updating the drivers for the USB, as well as the Arduino. And check your power management on the USB as well. I've seen Windows USB poop the bed if a device is connected / disconnected, or restarted several times in rapid succession. When this happens, sometimes Windows will think the port or device is faulty, and simply stop responding to its presence.

If *nix, make sure you've configured it properly.

Answer (score 0):

When an Arduino stops appearing, it is usually because it's fried. Especially if other machines appear when connected, and the faulty machine appears on no other machine.

Try [burning the bootloader](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP).

Comment: I do not the bootloader is broken as when I took the chip out of the board and put in into another board that board was able to be seen